# Multidimensional Chemical Space - nD coordinate system

Tags: cheminformatics

I have a dataset of many organic compounds.
I would like to describe them using a set of coordinates.
A 2D example of what I want to do is [chemplot](https://github.com/mcsorkun/ChemPlot), this package lets you create a 2D coordinate system to distinguish the chemicals and thus it creates a 2D chemical space.
It does that using some kind of decomposition technique (PCA, t-SNE, Umap) applied on the molecular representation that is said to be n-Dimensional.

Now what I want is actually the n-Dimensional representation of the molecules and not the simplified mapping on 2D space.
I read on the [article](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cmtd.202200005) that the procedure they use is the following

> ChemPlot uses the RDKit library to convert SMILES and InChI notations into ECFPs with a bit-vector length of 2,048 bits and radius of 2 adjacent atoms. After each molecule is converted, for all molecules, the bits that contain only 0 s or only 1 s are removed from the bit-vectors. The remaining number of bits determines the total number of dimensions and they are used as the input for the dimensionality reduction phase.

I would like some help on how to reproduce this process in python.
The 2 steps I would like help on are:

- How to get the 2048 bits vector (with radius of 2 atoms)
- How to clean the dimensions that only have 0s or 1s

Answer (score 1):

This is an open source package, well documented, using other packages (for classification and parameter reduction, e.g. [mordred](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-018-0258-y)) that are also open source.

This means you can download their python code and modify it, instead of reproducing it. All you have to do is to output the 2048 bits vector, and the shortened vectors. You would have to find the function where these are generated (or the function calls), and add a line to output the intermediate data you are interested in.

The details on how to do that are not chemistry, but computer programming, so I'll stop here.